# How to memorize German vocabulary by connecting it to English?

Tags: vocabulary, multiple-languages, english, german, language-comparison

My background vocabulary is English. Can you help me how to memorize German vocabulary by connecting the words with English?

Comment: Do a Google search for _English-German cognates_. You will find many lists of words that are identical or very similar in English and German. Examples: _winter-Winter, garden-Garten, mouse-Maus_.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two potential answers to your question.

1. The first answer involves **cognates**, as @Shoe already mentioned in the comment. There are many German-English cognates listed [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_German_cognates_with_English) and [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/common-english-german-cognates-4077037).
2. Another option that will take you much further is **mnemonics**, which in your case is using English for improving your memory of German words. Here is an example from [this page](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/german/how-to-learn-german-faster-mnemonics/):

> You can take the technique a little further by
>   compartmentalizing. Break down the word you want to learn into
>   different sounds and syllables. Associate each syllable with an image
>   and these images into a context that will let you remember their
>   sequence as well as give you the meaning.
>
> Let me give you an example: Let’s say want to learn the meaning of the
>   German word *wahrscheinlich*, which is “probably” or “probable”. It is
>   made up of *wahr*, *schein*, and *lich*.
>
> If you would like to anchor it on your brain, imagine there is a war
>   between pirate ships going on at sea. As fighting is going on all
>   around, you see one of the pirate captains standing on his bridge
>   looking at the scene and saying “arrr!” to himself (because what else
>   do pirates say?). At the same time, one of the crew members is
>   kneeling on the floor in front of him with a rug and putting a shine
>   on the captain’s shoes. His work is made even harder by the fact that
>   a black leech on this arm is sucking blood. Nervously the shoeshiner
>   looks up and asks, “Captain, are we going to win?” to which the latter
>   answers “Probably, mate. Most probably.”
>
> So how do you say “probably” in German? War + arrr! + shine + leech =
>   *Wahrscheinlich*.

3. And [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0964857901) is a book that combines **mnemonics** with German **cognates**.

Answer (score 0):

When encountering a difficult or unknown word in German, consult a German-German dictionary. Use one that contains the etymology (origin) of the words. This will allow you to notice similarities to English (as many words have the same origin), and allow you to break down the word into its component pieces, were possible. This can help in remembering the word, even when it does not necessarily provide a connection to English.